# Did Morpheus suffer any consequences for his actions?

Tags: god-of-war

Did Morpheus suffer any consequences for his actions in GoW Chains of Olympus? I mean, Persephone was killed and Atlas was chained with the weight of the World on his back.  But the only thing that was said about Morpheus is that he retreated. Considering that he took advantage of situation against the other gods isn't reasonable to think that he would be punished by Zeus in some way? Please, **I'm looking for sourced answers**.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I think (have not played the games, nor downvoted) because it is not a question that can be reliable answered. It is open for interpretation and discussion. And those kinds of questions are not really wanted here.

Comment: @Ids That's the point: I want to know if there is a reliable and sourced answer. Maybe there is something in the plot that I missed, that's the reason of my question.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include that you're looking for sourced answers. Right now, the phrasing "isn't it reasonable to think" sounds like a discussion question rather than an answerable one.

Comment: [Link to Meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/can-i-make-questions-about-lore-in-arqade)

Answer (score 1):

It is unknown if Morpheus suffered any consequences for his actions.

source: [Link](http://godofwar.wikia.com/wiki/Morpheus)